# Is it possible to extract a set of database rows with RestTemplate?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, repository, resttemplate

I am having difficulties getting multiple datasets out of my database with RestTemplate. I have many routines that extract a single row, with a format like:

```
IndicatorModel indicatorModel = restTemplate.getForObject(URL + id, 
IndicatorModel.class);
```

and they work fine. However, if I try to extract a set of data, such as:

```
Map<String, List<S_ServiceCoreTypeModel>> coreTypesMap = 
        restTemplate.getForObject(URL + id, Map.class);
```

this returns values in a

```
Map<String, LinkedHashMap<>>
```

format. Is there an easy way to return a List<> or Set<> in the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally the issue is that your Java object model does not match the structure of your json document. You are attempting to deserialize a single json element into a java List. Your JSON document looks like:

```
{
   "serviceCoreTypes":[
      {
         "serviceCoreType":{
            "name":"ALL",
            "description":"All",
            "dateCreated":"2016-06-23 14:46:32.09",
            "dateModified":"2016-06-23 14:46:32.09",
            "deleted":false,
            "id":1
         }
      },
      {
         "serviceCoreType":{
            "name":"HSI",
            "description":"High-speed Internet",
            "dateCreated":"2016-06-23 14:47:31.317",
            "dateModified":"2016-06-23 14:47:31.317",
            "deleted":false,
            "id":2
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But you cannot turn a `serviceCoreTypes` into a `List`, you can only turn a Json Array into a `List`. For instance if you removed the unnecessary wrapper elements from your json and your input document looked like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ALL",
    "description": "All",
    "dateCreated": "2016-06-23 14:46:32.09",
    "dateModified": "2016-06-23 14:46:32.09",
    "deleted": false,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "HSI",
    "description": "High-speed Internet",
    "dateCreated": "2016-06-23 14:47:31.317",
    "dateModified": "2016-06-23 14:47:31.317",
    "deleted": false,
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

You should be able to then deserialize THAT into a `List< S_ServiceCoreTypeModel>`. Alternately if you cannot change the json structure, you could create a Java object model that models the json document by creating some wrapper classes. Something like:

```
class ServiceCoreTypes {
  List<ServiceCoreType> serviceCoreTypes;
  ...
}
class ServiceCoreTypeWrapper {
  ServiceCoreType serviceCoreType;
  ...
}
class ServiceCoreType {
  String name;
  String description;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I created a wrapper that contained only the List<>. Code now works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't actually mean database, but instead a restful service as you're using RestTemplate

The problem you're facing is that you want to get a Collection back, but the `getForObject` method can only take in a single type parameter and cannot figure out what the type of the returned collection is.

I'd encourage you to consider using [`RestTemplate.exchange(...)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestOperations.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-)
which should allow you request for and receive back a collection type.

Comment: I see examples online using exchange(), that look like ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class). But if I declare a ResponseEntity<List<IndicatorModel>> result, I still can't pass the fourth parameter as List<IndicatorModel>.class, only as List.class - which leaves me with the same problem, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Please read the javadoc comment in the linked method. It gives that exact example

`ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyBean>> myBean = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyBean>>() {};`


`ResponseEntity<List<MyBean>> response = template.exchange("http://example.com",HttpMethod.GET, null, myBean);`

Comment: I like that solution; a lot cleaner than my workaround. I coded:

Comment: RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<S_ServiceCoreTypeModel>> myBean = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<S_ServiceCoreTypeModel>>() {}; 
ResponseEntity<List<S_ServiceCoreTypeModel>> response = restTemplate.exchange(TestBase.URL + coreTypeURL,HttpMethod.GET, null, myBean);
and got a nested JsonMappingException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token.

Comment: Looks like perhaps the json it's tryign to consume isn't actually a list of S_ServiceCoreTypeModel, did you validate the json is in the format you expect?

Comment: Ben - see solution I posted. This verifies that the HTTP response does contain JSON in the expected format, as an array of S_ServiceCoreType items. Maybe it has something to do with List<>?

Comment: Could you possibly post a sample of the json you're parsing? It looks like in the initial attempt you're trying to parse the entire document (as if it were an unwrapped list) into a  `List< S_ServiceCoreTypeModel>`. In the sample you did below, you're reading a property called  `serviceCoreTypes` from the document. Can you confirm which form your json takes:

  ```[{
   "foo": "bar"
  }, {
   "foo": "baz"
  }]```

or

```{
 "serviceCoreTypes": [{
  "foo": "bar"
 }, {
  "foo": "baz"
 }]
}```

Comment: Here is a partial display of the JSON: {
  "serviceCoreTypes": [
    {
      "serviceCoreType": {
        "name": "ALL",
        "description": "All",
        "dateCreated": "2016-06-23 14:46:32.09",
        "dateModified": "2016-06-23 14:46:32.09",
        "deleted": false,
        "id": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "serviceCoreType": {
        "name": "HSI",
        "description": "High-speed Internet",
        "dateCreated": "2016-06-23 14:47:31.317",
        "dateModified": "2016-06-23 14:47:31.317",
        "deleted": false,
        "id": 2
      }
    },...

Comment: That's your issue! Initially you were trying to parse that json to a list, but hte root of the json is not a list, it is a document with an element named `serviceCoreTypes` which itself is an array of single-element documents  `serviceCoreType`. 

I'll move the rest of this into a full comment so i can provide formatted code to explain

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works, for now at least. I would prefer a solution such as the one proposed by Ben, where I can get the HTTP response body as a list of items in the format I chose, but at least here I can extract each individual item from the JSON node. The code:

```
    S_ServiceCoreTypeModel endModel;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    JsonNode node = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, JsonNode.class);
    JsonNode allNodes = node.get("serviceCoreTypes");
    JsonNode oneNode = allNodes.get(1);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    endModel = objectMapper.readValue(oneNode.toString(), S_ServiceCoreTypeModel.class);
```

If anyone has thoughts on how to make Ben's solution work, I would love to hear it.